# installed mojo programming language but finding a repeating command when executed

Tags: python, apple-m1, modular, mojolang

1. I've installed mojo on my compute : and went to ran the code 'nano__.zprofile'
2. previously when downloading modular/mojo I ve got network issue, couple of times so I've done it multiple times
3. Now when I executed this command in the terminal and I am getting  "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"' multiple[precisely 3X times]
4. I need a detailed solution how to ommit or get rid of last 2 repetition of those lines5. Needed them in detail as I just started coding today, probably trying to learn....

Comment: `nano___.zprofile` is probably a shell script, and some installer has just appended that command multiple times.  Edit it with a text editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a Mojo but a Homebrew issue. To fix it, edit your `.zprofile` with nano inside the terminal with

`nano ~/.zprofile`.

There should be exactly **one** line related to Homebrew that reads

```
eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
```

Remove all duplicate lines. If you've added Homebrew to your PATH manually, you don't even need that one line. Try to comment it out and restart the terminal to check if that is the case.

See [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/orgs/Homebrew/discussions/446) for further information.